# How do I know if a component includes a binding on a directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a directive called `my-custom-directive`
This is how i'm using it

```
<my-component
    v-model="things.value"
    v-bind:error="things.error"
    v-my-custom-directive>
</my-component>
```

inside `my-custom-directive`, how do I know if `my-component` has the attribute `v-bind:error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [Vnode](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js)

`vnode.data.attrs` for DOM element (e.g. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/RMRBbw?editors=1111)

`vnode.componentOptions.propsData` for Vue Component (e.g. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/wmWxqd?editors=1011)

```
Vue.directive("focus", {
  // When the bound element is inserted into the DOM...
  inserted: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    if (
      vnode.data &&
      typeof vnode.data.attrs !== "undefined" &&
      vnode.data.attrs.hasOwnProperty("error")
    ) {
      // is DOM
    } else if (
      vnode.componentOptions &&
      typeof vnode.componentOptions.propsData !== "undefined" &&
      vnode.componentOptions.propsData.hasOwnProperty("error")
    ) {
        // is Vue Component
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I am getting `{}` in this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaWjQX?editors=1111

Comment: answer updated. pls use `vnode.componentOptions.propsData`